# How do I make a working accordion and animate the height of the content and the rotation of the arrow symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been struggling from fixing `classList.add` function and setting an element's property with `Javascript`. I want to animate and rotate the arrow symbol and animate the `height` of the content of the accordion.

I tried to animate the `height` of the content of the accordion by using `transition` property, but it seems it doesn't work, so I tried to set the property of its content itself(`h4` and `p` element) and added transition, but it doesn't work either.

I tried to use addList.add/remove function to animate and rotate the arrow symbol which is the `span` element, but it seems that it doesn't work, is it because of the `span` element that causes this to occur?

```js
var c1Tab1AccCB = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-acc-cb");
var c1Tab1AccBTN = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-acc-btn");
var c1Tab1Content = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content");
var c1Tab1ContentH4 = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content-h4");
var c1Tab1ContentP = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content-p");
var c1Tab1AccBTNArrow = document.querySelector(".c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(2)");
var accordionArrow = document.getElementById("accordion-arrow");

c1Tab1AccCB.addEventListener("change", function() {
  accordionToggle();
});

function accordionToggle() {
  if (c1Tab1AccCB.checked == true) {

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CONTENT'S HEIGHT TO ANIMATE*/
    c1Tab1Content.style.height = "auto";
    c1Tab1Content.style.paddingBottom = "20px";
    c1Tab1ContentH4.style.height = "100%";
    c1Tab1ContentP.style.height = "100%";
    /*c1Tab1Content.style.display = "block";*/
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add("active-accordion-btn");
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove.hover("c1-tab1-acc-btn");

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE ADD CLASS OR SET THE PROPERTY OF THE SPAN ELEMENT*/
    /*c1Tab1AccBTNArrow.classList.add("active-accordion-arrow");
    accordionArrow.classList.add("active-accordion-arrow");*/
    accordionArrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    /*accordionArrow.style.display = "none";*/
  } else {
    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CONTENT'S HEIGHT TO ANIMATE*/
    c1Tab1Content.style.height = "0";
    c1Tab1Content.style.paddingBottom = "0";
    c1Tab1ContentH4.style.height = "0";
    c1Tab1ContentP.style.height = "0";
    /*c1Tab1Content.style.display = "none";*/

    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove("active-accordion-btn");
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add.hover("c1-tab1-acc-btn");

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE ADD CLASS OR SET THE PROPERTY OF THE SPAN ELEMENT*/
    /*c1Tab1AccBTNArrow.classList.remove("active-accordion-arrow");
    accordionArrow.classList.remove("active-accordion-arrow");*/
    accordionArrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }
}
accordionToggle();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -47.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 95%;
  /*max-width: 512px;*/
  height: auto;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 17px 50px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


/*@media (min-width: 568.6666666666665px) {
  .tabs {
    margin-left: -256px;
  }
}*/

.c1-tab1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.c1-tab1-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #333;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-cb {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4%;
  left: -4%;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: calc(-50% - 2.5px);
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  color: #1e5cd9;
  border: 3px solid #3d1ed9;
  border-top-color: #1ebad9;
  border-left-color: #1ebad9;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-size: calc(0.9375rem + 0.46875vw);
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn:hover {
  background: #1e5cd9;
  color: #fff;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn:active {
  border: 3px solid #1ebad9;
  border-top-color: #3d1ed9;
  border-left-color: #3d1ed9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 17px 12.5px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19) inset;
}

.active-accordion-btn {
  background: #1e5cd9;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #1ebad9;
  border-top-color: #3d1ed9;
  border-left-color: #3d1ed9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 17px 12.5px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19) inset;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: center;
  left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.active-accordion-text {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: center;
  left: 20px;
  float: left;
}


/*.c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(2)*/

.accordion-arrow {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.active-accordion-arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.c1-tab1-content {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-top: 48px;*/
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1e5cd9;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 17px 50px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  /*padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;*/
  transition-property: height, padding bottom;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  /*transition: height ease 0.2s;*/
}

.c1-tab1-content h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

.c1-tab1-content p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: distribute;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align-last: left;
  margin: 20px 20px 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="c1-tab1">
      <form class="c1-tab1-form">
        <input type="checkbox" class="c1-tab1-acc-cb" id="c1-tab1-acc-cb" />
        <label
          for="c1-tab1-acc-cb"
          class="c1-tab1-acc-btn"
          id="c1-tab1-acc-btn"
        >
          <span>1st Song</span>
          <span class="accordion-arrow" id="accordion-arrow">&#10148;</span>
        </label>
      </form>
      <div class="c1-tab1-content" id="c1-tab1-content">
        <h4 id="c1-tab1-content-h4">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h4>
        <p id="c1-tab1-content-p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim adminim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi utaliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor inreprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nullapariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt inculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add.hover("c1-tab1-acc-btn");` this is throwing an error in your code. Remove the ***.hover*** from that line and it works in my test, the arrow animation works when clicked.

Comment: I think only it's because it's not compatble with the IDE of the stackoverflow, and it works on my browser. Try to run it in full page to see.The issue here is that it's not animating properly and the Arrow symbol is not rotating.

Comment: I tested in full screen as well when I remove the .hover, which is a jQuery function not vanilla JS, which is what you have in your post, it works, the arrow spins. I will post an example as an answer showing the working arrow animation.

Comment: Okay thanks. But one last issue how do I animate the content properly when it collapses?

Comment: Exactly how do you want it to animate?

Comment: Typically you need to have some kind of transition or animation on the selectors it will be returning to.

Comment: When the content is being collapsed, it looks terrible and it doesn't look smooth

Comment: The animation for padding works alright but the height doesn't animate even though I declared for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I want to animate and rotate the arrow symbol and animate the height of the content of the accordion.***

In `if (c1Tab1AccCB.checked == true) {` you have the following line `c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove.hover("c1-tab1-acc-btn");` why did you put `.hover` is for your code looks to be vanilla JS not jQuery, remove this so it reads `c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove("c1-tab1-acc-btn");`, furthermore in the `else` portion of your conditional, you have the following, `c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add.hover("c1-tab1-acc-btn");`, again remove the `.hover` from that line of code and your conditional should work ***adding/removing*** the class with the animation to spin the arrow.

```js
var c1Tab1AccCB = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-acc-cb");
var c1Tab1AccBTN = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-acc-btn");
var c1Tab1Content = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content");
var c1Tab1ContentH4 = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content-h4");
var c1Tab1ContentP = document.getElementById("c1-tab1-content-p");
var c1Tab1AccBTNArrow = document.querySelector(".c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(2)");
var accordionArrow = document.getElementById("accordion-arrow");

c1Tab1AccCB.addEventListener("change", function() {
  accordionToggle();
});

function accordionToggle() {
  if (c1Tab1AccCB.checked == true) {

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CONTENT'S HEIGHT TO ANIMATE*/
    c1Tab1Content.style.height = "auto";
    c1Tab1Content.style.paddingBottom = "20px";
    c1Tab1ContentH4.style.height = "100%";
    c1Tab1ContentP.style.height = "100%";
    /*c1Tab1Content.style.display = "block";*/
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add("active-accordion-btn");
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove("c1-tab1-acc-btn");

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE ADD CLASS OR SET THE PROPERTY OF THE SPAN ELEMENT*/
    /*c1Tab1AccBTNArrow.classList.add("active-accordion-arrow");
    accordionArrow.classList.add("active-accordion-arrow");*/
    accordionArrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    /*accordionArrow.style.display = "none";*/
  } else {
    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CONTENT'S HEIGHT TO ANIMATE*/
    c1Tab1Content.style.height = "0";
    c1Tab1Content.style.paddingBottom = "0";
    c1Tab1ContentH4.style.height = "0";
    c1Tab1ContentP.style.height = "0";
    /*c1Tab1Content.style.display = "none";*/

    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.remove("active-accordion-btn");
    c1Tab1AccBTN.classList.add("c1-tab1-acc-btn");

    /*THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE ADD CLASS OR SET THE PROPERTY OF THE SPAN ELEMENT*/
    /*c1Tab1AccBTNArrow.classList.remove("active-accordion-arrow");
    accordionArrow.classList.remove("active-accordion-arrow");*/
    accordionArrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }
}
accordionToggle();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -47.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 95%;
  /*max-width: 512px;*/
  height: auto;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 17px 50px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


/*@media (min-width: 568.6666666666665px) {
  .tabs {
    margin-left: -256px;
  }
}*/

.c1-tab1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.c1-tab1-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #333;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-cb {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4%;
  left: -4%;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: calc(-50% - 2.5px);
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  color: #1e5cd9;
  border: 3px solid #3d1ed9;
  border-top-color: #1ebad9;
  border-left-color: #1ebad9;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-size: calc(0.9375rem + 0.46875vw);
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn:hover {
  background: #1e5cd9;
  color: #fff;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn:active {
  border: 3px solid #1ebad9;
  border-top-color: #3d1ed9;
  border-left-color: #3d1ed9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 17px 12.5px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19) inset;
}

.active-accordion-btn {
  background: #1e5cd9;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #1ebad9;
  border-top-color: #3d1ed9;
  border-left-color: #3d1ed9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 17px 12.5px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19) inset;
}

.c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: center;
  left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.active-accordion-text {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: center;
  left: 20px;
  float: left;
}


/*.c1-tab1-acc-btn span:nth-child(2)*/

.accordion-arrow {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.active-accordion-arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.c1-tab1-content {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-top: 48px;*/
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1e5cd9;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 17px 50px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  /*padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;*/
  transition-property: height, padding bottom;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  /*transition: height ease 0.2s;*/
}

.c1-tab1-content h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

.c1-tab1-content p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: distribute;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align-last: left;
  margin: 20px 20px 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="c1-tab1">
      <form class="c1-tab1-form">
        <input type="checkbox" class="c1-tab1-acc-cb" id="c1-tab1-acc-cb" />
        <label
          for="c1-tab1-acc-cb"
          class="c1-tab1-acc-btn"
          id="c1-tab1-acc-btn"
        >
          <span>1st Song</span>
          <span class="accordion-arrow" id="accordion-arrow">&#10148;</span>
        </label>
      </form>
      <div class="c1-tab1-content" id="c1-tab1-content">
        <h4 id="c1-tab1-content-h4">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h4>
        <p id="c1-tab1-content-p">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim adminim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi utaliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor inreprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nullapariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt inculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```